# Using tensorflow on Android NDK side directly (Not using JAVA api)

Tags: android, c++, tensorflow, android-ndk

I am trying to run a neural network on Android in C++. The examples (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/android) show how to use tensorflow using JAVA apis which call C++ using JNI functions. Has anyone tried to use tensorflow directly in C++ on Android? How can the tensorflow library be built and linked for using C++ apis on Android. Can you please guide me on that? I want to use C++ apis on Android in the similar way as done in iOS examples.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I solved this problem. Although there is not much documentation of using c++ apis on android and compiling and linking tensorflow to NDK, the makefile have important comments as well as there are associated scripts. Compilation steps are very similar to that of ios.

1. Install following dependencies a)autoconf b) automake c)automake. Then run tensorflow/contrib/makefile/download_dependencies.sh; I ran on May 10, 2017 repository for the first time, when it worked perfectly. In the later version around June 1, due to some changes in tensorflow/workspace.bzl, that I do not understand in download_dependencies.sh fails to recognise the tar files download_dependencies is trying to download. I just replaced workspace.bzl from May 10 repo commit.
2. Step 2 is to run tensorflow/contrib/makefile/compile_android_protobuf.sh like this

   NDK_ROOT=absolute/path/to/ndk/folder ./tensorflow/contrib/makefile/compile_android_protobuf.sh
3. Run make. But first you may need to make some changes in Makefile. Replace -fPIE flags with -fPIC flags. Also add -fPIC flag to HOST_CXXFLAGS. Then run make like this:

   make -f tensorflow/contrib/makefile/Makefile TARGET=ANDROID NDK_ROOT=absolute/path/to/ndk/folder

   Alternatively one can also run build_all_android.sh which runs all 3 steps in one go, but you may need to do Makefile changes for flags.

This generated tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/protobuf/lib/libprotobuf.a and tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/libtensorflow-core.a; This can be linked to Android NDK project in Android.mk file under LOCAL_LDLIBS. One should use these Linked flags `-Wl,--build-id -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition -Wl,--whole-archive` Also -std=c++11 in LOCAL_CFLAGS in Android.mk file and APP_STL := gnustl_shared in Application.mk file.

This should be sufficient to build a shared library of your NDK project.

Comment: Any idea how to make this work in new Android with CMake instead? I have tried a bunch of things, but have not been able to use C++ tensorflow calls with android NDK C++ code.

Comment: hi，build_all_android.sh is build tensorflow inference, which is an old version, any idea about build tensflow lite with ndk build.

Answer (score 0):

100% possible, with a small caveat...

Most of Android's UI is done in Java.  You can create a [native activity](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master-cmake/native-activity), but to get any output to the screen, you need to either use OpenGL (which doesn't have all the nice Android UI Views) or you will need to transition the JNI barrier to get your data output *to* and *from* the native code to display to the user.

Depending on your familiarity with OpenGLES, EGL, etc..  You might opt to transition the JNI barrier instead of creating a native_activity, but at a much smaller cross section.

You could create a Runnable and signal it when there's work to be performed.  Use a concurrent queue (in Java) to submit work and another (concurrent) queue to receive results from. The Runnable pops the work queue, calls a single JNI/C function to submit the work and return a JSON string.  Then it submits the work to the finished queue.

Comment: I am sorry if my question wasn't clear. I am not concerned about the UI part at all. That I will anyways handle by passing data by JNI.
My question is regarding how to build tensorflow for android and include it in android project to call tensorflow apis on C++ side of Android app. I have image buffer on C++ side which I want to run though a neural net without sending it over to JAVA.